# Dygraphs, can you color sections of a graph in the same series?

Tags: dygraphs

I haven't seen how you can make one section of a graph blue, then one green, etc.  You can do different series, but that is of no use to me.  I want to have a section, say from time x to time y one color, then time y to time z another.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality isn't possible in dygraphs as a native piece of functionality. However, it can be achieved by providing the different 'sections' of your curve as completely different timeseries. This is pretty straight forward.

You could write a function where you pass an array of datetimes as the argument, in addition to the original timeseries. The function would then split apart the timeseries based on your array of datetimes, and return a set of dygraph friendly arrays which you could plot as normal.

Dygraphs does a pretty good job of picking some colors for you, but if you want to control that yourself, you could do the following.

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("yourDiv"),
    data,
    {
        colors: ["#123123", '#321312', '#222333', '#111222']
    }       
);
```

where data is a correctly formatted [dygraph data array](http://dygraphs.com/data.html). You will almost certainly want to specify some other options when configuring your dygraph, but in the example code above I have shown you how to do the colours for the different series.

To split your timeseries it's a little involved, but not really. In the above code I assume that you have 4 different timeseries, and therefore 4 different colors. If you need help splitting your timeseries, I would suggest that you think carefully about how you might want to achieve that in pseudo code (or any coding language you know) and I will be happy to take you through in is JS.

For example, let's say your individual timeseries is as follows:

```
var basicTimeseries = [
    [1384337076000, 123],
    [1384337077000, 321],
    [1384337078000, 111],
    [1384337079000, 222],
    [1384337080000, 333],
    [1384337081000, 132],
    [1384337082000, 321],
    [1384337083000, 122],
    [1384337084000, 322],
    [1384337085000, 333]
]
```

where this is an array of arrays, where in the secondary (inner) arrays you have your ms timestamp and then your value. Say you want to separate this into three separate timeseries based on some rule that you already know (e.g. data before 1384337079000, data after this & before 1384337082000, and data after this until the end of time) and you have already established that you want to break your timeseries into three different curves. You now want to plot these on dygraphs. You should already be aware of the data structure that dygraphs accepts. For example:

```
var dygraphData = [
    [X1,Y1, ... , N1],
    [X2,Y2, ... , N2],
    [X3,Y3, ... , N3],
    [X4,Y4, ... , N4]
]
```

where the data structure is array of arrays, where in the secondy (inner) array houses your x-axis value, and then the point for each of your timeseries curves at that specific x-axis value.

You could do as follows:

```
var dygraphData = []; // Initialise
$each.(basicTimeseries, function (i,e) {
    dygraphData[i] = []; // Initialise
    if ( e[0] < 1384337076000 ) {
        dygraphData[i].push([e[0], e[1], NaN, NaN]); // Push the x-axis and 1st curve
    } else if ( e[0] >= 1384337076000 && e[0] < 1384337082000) {
        dygraphData[i].push([e[0], NaN, e[1], NaN]); // Push the x-axis and 2nd curve
    } else if ( e[0] >= 1384337082000) {
        dygraphData[i].push([e[0], NaN, NaN, e[1]]); // Push the x-axis and 3rd curve
    } else {
        console.log("How did this happen?");
    }
});
```

Obviously the code above is overly verbose and pretty rigid, but it should help you understand what is going on. You can then call dygraphs passing dygraphData as your data-set.

Comment: OK, being pretty naive at Javascript, I do need some hand holding. I get that based upon timestamps (which I do have interval data provided) I need to separate the data. Thing is, how do I specify a color. I couldn't get what I needed from the documentation.  So, if I have say, 500 data points, which we can call tdata[500], then how do I get tdata[0-100] to be blue?

Comment: What you need is provided in the documentation just fine: http://dygraphs.com/options.htm - I'll update my answer to provide a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have a natural breaking point for my series of data.  I get time value pairs, so think of it as ms, value1.. then after a while the variable of value1 changes to value2, so if we look at my data:  ms, value1....ms, value1.... ms, value2, and so on.

Comment: So I'm looking to separate my data when this value changes, so I want to create a double array: so I have say data = [], then inside of that, element = []; so in my loop of going through the data, I was looking at element.push(new Date(time)); element.push(value1) ... etc. When the value var changes, so ends my series.  Basically, when value1 is null, then my series ended, and I get value2.  Those are all to be color coded dynamically as the color matters.

Comment: Have you spent time with dygraphs, making sure you understand the correct data format? It seems like your problem here isn't really a dygraphs problem, but more of a general data formatting problem.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was able to get the intervals going today.  Quite happy.  I was able to use a double loop and set up the data.  We had our color routine already set up for it, so I was able to just create a simple color array and pass that as a parameter.  Worked right out of the box.  Next thing I have to do is be able to shade an area based on time.  So, I will be looking up on how to do that.  It's a must have.  Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, you'll notice your question got a lot of downvotes - that's basically because it was too broad and not specific to dygraphs. If you continue to use Stackoverflow (and I suggest you do), you need to provide more specific problems and questions.